# iPod mini controls disabled when certain audio session parameters are set

Tags: iphone, ipad, audio, ios4

I'm working on a music visualizer for the iPhone/iPad, under iOS 3 you could double-tap the home button and get iPod controls. With the latest version 4.1-4.2, these controls are now grayed out when the home button is pressed. I found a similar complaint at http://openradar.appspot.com/8696944, although there wasn't a solution.

I have the base sound category set to `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord`, with `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers` set to true. (Just to add more fun to the problem I'm using OpenAL for some sound effects.)

I have tried setting the category back to ambient when the application goes into the background. but either it happens too late or it's not sufficient.

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem... been stuck on it for hours. I'm using openAL too - guessing this has something to do with it. Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here's where I've got to so far:

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, self);
UInt32  sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);

devicetwo = alcOpenDevice(NULL);
contexttwo = alcCreateContext(devicetwo, 0);

    //The following two lines are the lines that gray out iPod controls:

alcMakeContextCurrent(contexttwo); 
AudioSessionSetActive(YES);
```

The iPod controls remain grayed out even once the app quits... And removing the two culprit lines of code result in no sound being produced in the app.

Comment: Nope I'm still baffled, I've tried shutting down the sound listener in applicationWillResignActive and applicationDidEnterBackground, no dice. I'm using both openAL and the sound listener library (http://github.com/stephencelis/sc_listener) So it's alway been a bit tricky to keep the whole thing happy, a combination of play and record, and then allowing mix with others, and rerouting the audio from the "receiver" to the speaker. This is definitely a change in iOS, since I've had 3 apps out for 6 mo+ that had some music visualization (ibeams and gravilocity) And I've only recently noticed this

Answer (score 1):

Well I've given up.. I'm now coding my own UI based off of the AddMusic example code
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

I'm happy to report that play and stop via the MPMusicPlayerController doesn't seem to conflict with the play and record session settings. And building your own play/pause/FF seems to be fairly straightforward

p.s. I've also discovered that this Music Visualizer app: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/music-visualizer/id337651694?mt=8 is just this addMusic sample uploaded and this guy is charging 2 bucks for it.. It's got awful reviews.. but it still seems wrong that it's on the app store.

Answer (score 0):

My iPod touch 4G is running iOS 4.2, and it doesn't have this problem. I would attempt to contact Apple.

Comment: I've got a iPad and a iPhone 3GS and I've tested this on a iPhone 4. All have this problem.

Comment: Don't downvote my answer. I'm saying I don't have the problem, so you should contact Apple. This is a technical support query for them, and frankly isn't appropriate for stackexchange anyway.